# How to pass values in another servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

from and subject are constants strings and other values I get from jsp

```
String from = " "  ; //constant string

String subject = " "  ; //constant string

// code get from mail.jsp
String mail = request.get Parameter("mail");

String message = request.get Parameter("text");

String login = request.get Parameter("login");

String password = request.get Parameter("password");   

System.out.print(""+mail);
System.out.print(""+from);
System.out.print(""+subject);
System.out.print(""+text);
System.out.print(""+login);
System.out.print(""+password);`
```

How can I pass multiple string values to another servlet

Answer (score 0):

Set your variable as context **attribute**.

```
getServletContext().setAttribute("mail", mail);
```

and use `getServletContext().getAttribute("mail")` to get the value in another servlet.